# Need to implement a mjpeg stream

Tags: http, mjpeg, mongoose-web-server

I would like to implement a MJPEG stream using the mongoose lightweight web server. Can someone give me some pointers on how I effectively do that? I already have the jpeg files that I need to stream and I understand the MJPEG concept. I just need to know how can I implement the MJPEG stream from a protocol level.

Answer (score 2):

mjpeg over http as implemented by almost all ip cameras is a subtype of multipart mime message. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Mixed-Replace

you have to replace the cvloop() with your implementation that fill the jbuf.

```
#include <vector>
#include "mongoose.h"

#ifdef _WIN32 
#include <windows.h>
#define SLEEP(ms) Sleep(ms)
#endif
#ifdef __linux__ 
#define SLEEP(ms) usleep(ms*1000)
#endif

std::vector<unsigned char> jbuf;//fill this with a single jpeg image data

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
void cvloop()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("c:/toprocess/frame_%004d.jpg");
    cv::Mat frame;
    for(;;)
    {
        cap>>frame;
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
        std::vector<int> param(2);
        param[0]=CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
        param[1]=40;
        imencode(".jpg",frame,buffer,param);
        jbuf.swap(buffer);
        SLEEP(50);
    }
}

// This function will be called by mongoose on every new request.
static int begin_request_handler(struct mg_connection *conn) {
    mg_printf(conn,
        "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=b\r\n"
        "Cache-Control: no-store\r\n"
        "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "\r\n");
    for(;;)
    {
        if( jbuf.size()<4 || 
            (jbuf[0]!=0xff && jbuf[0]!=0xd8) ||
            (jbuf[jbuf.size()-2]!=0xff && jbuf[jbuf.size()-1]!=0xd9))
        {
            SLEEP(10);
            continue;
        }
        mg_printf(conn,
            "--b\r\n"
            "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
            "Content-length: %d\r\n"
            "\r\n",jbuf.size());
        int ret=mg_write(conn,&jbuf[0], jbuf.size());
        if(ret==0||ret==-1) return 1;
        SLEEP(50);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    struct mg_context *ctx;
    struct mg_callbacks callbacks;

    // List of options. Last element must be NULL.
    const char *options[] = {"listening_ports", "8080",NULL};

    // Prepare callbacks structure. We have only one callback, the rest are NULL.
    memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
    callbacks.begin_request = begin_request_handler;

    // Start the web server.
    ctx = mg_start(&callbacks, NULL, options);
    cvloop();

    // Wait until user hits "enter". Server is running in separate thread.
    // Navigating to http://localhost:8080 will invoke begin_request_handler().
    getchar();

    // Stop the server.
    mg_stop(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of the server you have used?

Comment: Also this code seems to block and only provide stream to a single client

Comment: Hi, that was a long time ago, so I can't remember the exact version. Regardless, if you want more control, you can use boost for that.  The same functionality can be implemented in less than 100 lines of code.

Comment: Here's some example code, which unfortunately has a lot of other stuff. But the relevant portions are easy to extract. Hope it helps. https://gist.github.com/zawlin/6ac0395c3e51bdce975f9f35896a7553